# In dynamic SQL, table is not being created

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to use the configurations table to create a table if the table_status is new, and I have written the code but the table 'Dimcampaign' is not being created.

Comment: Besides missing spaces, `@tablename` contains the literal string `'select tablename from dbo.configuration'`. And likewise for all the other variables

Comment: All your `EXEC (@SQL)` statements (though you should be using `sys.sp_executesql`) are commented out, so I'm not sure why you would expect the objects to be created; none of your dynamic statements are executed. Plus, as @HoneyBadger said, `Create tableselect Datatypes from dbo.configuration(select Newcolumn from dbo.configuration)` is never going to work.

Comment: @larnu  Sir, as per your advice, I removed the comments and executed it. It still does not create or alter the tables. and the latter part, i didn't understand, how should I fix it?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I m sorry, but i am new to this. How should i fix this?

Comment: Well, no, as I and @HoneyBadger  have stated, `Create tableselect Datatypes from dbo.configuration(select Newcolumn from dbo.configuration)` isn't valid syntax. For staters, there's no such object type as a `TABLESELECT`.

Comment: The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is the `PRINT`/`SELECT` it; you'll quickly see how malformed your queries are if you do that.

Comment: I would use a cursor for this. The problem is that executing some sql string is not assigning the result of that query to anything (wouldn't make sense anyway). Use a cursor on `dbo.configuration` and iterate through its rows.

Comment: ok sir, i will try.

Comment: @HoneyBadger actually sir, we have to use stored procedure with dynamic sql we can't use any other method

Comment: You can use a cursor in a stored procedure. The cursor is just where you build and execute the sql for each row in the `dbo.configuration` table

Answer (score 0):

Initially you set `@Tablestatus` to a SQL statement, but the `while` loop requires `@Tablestatus = 'New'`.  You should change how you initialize your `@Tablestatus` variable so that the logic flows into the `while` loop.

I would guess that you actually want `@Tablestatus` to be initialized to the value in your `dbo.configuration` table.  For example:

```
declare @Tablestatus varchar(MAX)
select @Tablestatus = tablestatus from dbo.configuration
```

That being said, your `while` loop does not have a way to terminate.  For example, inside the loop you should reset `@Tablestatus` so that it can become something other than `'New'` so the loop can end.

For example:

```
while @Tablestatus = 'New' begin 
  -- maybe do some stuff here
  update dbo.configuration set tablestatus = 'Old'
  -- maybe do some other stuff here
  select @Tablestatus = tablestatus from dbo.configuration
end
```

Looking a little more at your post, I don't really understand why you have a `while` loop there.  It looks like you want something like this:

```
-- Initialize variables with values from dbo.configuration
declare @Tablestatus varchar(MAX)
select @Tablestatus = tablestatus from dbo.configuration

declare @If_New_Table_then_PrimaryKey NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @If_New_Table_then_PrimaryKey = If_New_Table_then_PrimaryKey from dbo.configuration

declare @NewColumn varchar(max)
select @NewColumn = Newcolumn from dbo.configuration

declare @Datatypes NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @Datatypes = Datatypes from dbo.configuration


declare @sql varchar(100) 

-- Now that your variables are initialized you 
-- can use the variables to take the appropriate action
if @Tablestatus = 'New' and @If_New_Table_then_PrimaryKey = 'Yes'
    begin
      set @sql = 'Create table' + @tablename + '(' + @Newcolumn + @Datatypes + ' PRIMARY KEY' + '(' + @Newcolumn + ')' + ');' 
      print (@sql)
      exec(@sql)
    end

if @Tablestatus = 'Old'
    begin
      set @sql = 'Alter table' + @tablename + 'ADD' + @Newcolumn + @Datatypes
      print (@sql)
      exec(@sql)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I like playing around with cursors and dynamic SQL. Something like this should do the trick, I'd add a whole lot of checking though! What if tablename contains spaces (you might like to use `QUOTENAME`), or what if datatypes doesn't contain a valid datatype? Etc etc, I can think of 100 things that can go wrong. Generally, when you want to do this, you need to rethink your design. But I have been in situations where I had to do something similar.

```
DECLARE @Tablestatus NVARCHAR(4000)
,       @tablename NVARCHAR(4000)
,       @If_New_Table_then_PrimaryKey NVARCHAR(4000)
,       @NewColumn NVARCHAR(4000)
,       @Datatypes NVARCHAR(4000)
,       @sql NVARCHAR(4000);

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT  tablestatus
    ,       tablename
    ,       If_New_Table_then_PrimaryKey
    ,       Newcolumn
    ,       Datatypes
    FROM    dbo.configuration;

OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur
INTO @Tablestatus
,   @tablename
,   @If_New_Table_then_PrimaryKey
,   @NewColumn
,   @Datatypes;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN;
        IF  @Tablestatus = 'New'
        AND @If_New_Table_then_PrimaryKey = 'Yes'
            BEGIN;
                SET @sql = N'Create table ' + @tablename + N'(' + @NewColumn + N' ' + @Datatypes + N' PRIMARY KEY' + N'(' + @NewColumn + N')' + N');';
                PRINT ( @sql );
                EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
            END

        IF @Tablestatus = 'Old'
            BEGIN;
                SET @sql = N'Alter table ' + @tablename + N'ADD ' + @NewColumn + N' ' +@Datatypes;
                PRINT ( @sql );
                EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
            END;


        FETCH NEXT FROM cur
        INTO @Tablestatus
        ,   @tablename
        ,   @If_New_Table_then_PrimaryKey
        ,   @NewColumn
        ,   @Datatypes
    END;


CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Comment: so, my teacher said, that what i was doing is right,  but there is mistake in the while loop, coz when checking if tablestatus=new or not it is returning multiple values. She said, i have to use identity column for it, could you help me with that

Comment: sir this method is creating only one column of the table, and what if i have multiple tables with "new status"